# Django: Problems changing the current language

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-templates

I want to change the current language of my page.

I'm using this HTML code to make the buttons:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}" />
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right language menu">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <li>
                <h1>{{ language }}</h1>
                <button type="submit"
                        name="language"
                        value="{{ language.code }}"
                        class="{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected{% endif %}">
                    {{ language.name_local }}
                </button>

            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</form>
```

I have no problems when I'm switching from Spanish 'es' to US English 'en-us' but when I try to switch from US English to Spanish send me this error:

**Not Found:** /i18n/setlang/-us/

Answer (score 0):

Make teamplatetags in your djangp apps like below:

**Templatetag file**

```
from django import template
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, reverse, Resolver404
from django.utils.translation import get_language, activate

register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def change_lang(context, lang=None, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Get active page's url by a specified language
    Usage: {% change_lang 'en' %}
    """
    path = context['request'].path
    full_path = context['request'].get_full_path()
    try:
        url_parts = resolve(path)
        cur_language = get_language()
        try:
            activate(lang)
            url = reverse(url_parts.view_name, kwargs=url_parts.kwargs)
            activate(cur_language)
            parameters = "?{0}".format(full_path.split('?')[1]) if len(full_path.split('?')) == 2 else ""
            return "{0}{1}".format(url, parameters)
        except Exception:
            pass
    except Resolver404:
        pass
    return full_path
```

**HTML**

```
{% load <templatetag file> %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
<ul>
{% for language in languages %}
   {% if not language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% change_lang language.code %}">{{ language.name_local }}</a>
    </li>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

http://www.neerajbyte.com/snippet/change-language-in-template-using-templatetag-in-d/